# Which way is correct to represent this differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$3x^2+x^3$$

**Option 1**

$$\frac{d}{dx}(3x^2+x^3)=6x+3x^2$$

**Option 2**

$$\frac{d(3x^2+x^3)}{dx}=6x+3x^2$$

My student wrote the Option 2 style, not sure whether I can consider is ok or not.

Comment: Are you honestly asking, as a teacher, if this is correct?! This is one of the first things I learnt as a student...

Comment: Both are correct, I suppose technically, the option $2$ answer could be interpreted as the 'operator' definition of the derivative, but in any case both options are equivalent.

Comment: Also, [wikipedia is your friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation)

Comment: @lioness99a i am relatively new to teaching so yeah. I know both representations are okay to me but my sister is not happy about it because the second representation looks "weird". So i am here to ask for others opinion for more concrete evidence.

Comment: @user450199 Is your sister also a mathematician? If you are happy with it, then your question should not be "is this correct", but more "why are these equal"

Comment: @lioness99a she did physics for her degree. I did chemistry for my degree but ended up teaching mathematics.

Comment: @user450199 Both variants are common. I think it is a good thing that you consider to ask the internet instead of just not giving point for something that might be your fault for not knowing the notation.

Comment: To me, your question as posed is fine, btw

Comment: @Bacon I never said the quesion asked was incorrect in any way, I'm just surprised at the lack of research done first - a quick google of "differentation notation" pulled up the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation) which cleared it up in no time

Comment: @lioness99a yeah whatever. Yes I do not know how to call this category as you called it "differentiation notation". I am not a maths major so I only know how to calculate and use formula.

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you. I think i will stick to option 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct, but represent slightly different ways of thinking about the derivative (at least in my mind).

When I read option 1, what I think is that you have this "machine" called "the derivative" which is written $\frac d{dx}$. You feed functions to it, and it gives you a (potentially) different function back which is related to the function you gave it by taking the relevant limits, or more intuitively by finding the "steepness" of $f$ at all points.

As for option 2, it makes me think that for any function $f$, you have an associated function called "the derivative of $f$" which is written $\frac{df}{dx}$ (even though it looks like it consists of four letters and a line, it's really just one big symbol, kind of like how the letter 'i' is just one symbol even though it consists of both a line and a dot). It is defined by the relevant limit-taking or steepness-interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the given representations are equivalent.

For:
$$y(x)=3x^2+x^3$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} \equiv \frac{d(3x^2+x^3)}{dx} \equiv \frac{d}{dx}(3x^2+x^3) \equiv  \frac{d(3x^2)}{dx}+\frac{d(x^3)}{dx} \equiv \frac{d}{dx}(3x^2)+\frac{d}{dx}(x^3) 
=6x+3x^2$$